# Часы "Сколько времени страницы с момента его создания" JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

Нужно создать часы которые отобразят сколько времени странице, (СС ММ ЧЧ ДД), в разных блоках.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так

```js
const dateCreate = Date.now()

function calculate() {
  let s = Math.floor((Date.now() - dateCreate) / 1000)
  return {
    s: s % 60,
    m: Math.floor(s / 60) % 60,
    h: Math.floor(s / 3600) % 24,
    d: Math.floor(s / 86400),
  }
}

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(calculate()))
}, 1000)
```

Найти все элементы

```js
const els = {
  s: document.getElementById(elementId)
  // и т.д - m,h,d 
}
```

А через таймер запустить установку

```js
function setDate(){
  const t = calculate()
  for (let [p,el] of Object.entries(els)) {
    el.textContent = t[p].toString(10).padStart(2, '0')
  }
}

setInterval(setDate, 1000)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но есть еще вопрос... Как связать это с моим кодом? Код добавил к вопросу (скриншот #2)

Comment: @MADARA добавил

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null

Теперь вот такая ошибка в данном коде:

function setDate(){
  const t = calculate()
  for (let [p,el] of Object.entries(els)) {
    el.textContent = t[p].toString(10).padStart(2, '0')
  }
}

Comment: @MADARA Так а код то был немного изменен `s: document.getElementById("sec")` и так со всеми четырьмя элементами, для каждого из свойств `s,m,h,d`

Comment: Я сделал именно так, но что-то не вышло. ```s: document.getElementById('sec'),
  m: document.getElementById('min'),
  h: document.getElementById('chas'),
  d: document.getElementById('dney')```

Comment: @MADARA попробуй в консоль выведи, сразу первой строкой в цикле `console.log(el)`, а `el.textContent` пока заккоменти. Или так посмотреть `console.log(els)` - может он элементы не находит

Comment: @MADARA а догадался. Подключи в своей разметке скрипт в самый конец body, конечно он ничего не найдет.

Comment: ```{s: null, m: null, h: null, d: null}
d: null
h: null
m: null
s: null```

Да, похоже и вправду не видит

Comment: Не совсем понял, скрипт "body"?

Comment: @MADARA не видит потому как скрипт запускается до создания элементов - у тебя SCRIPT в начале body. Перемести это в конец

Comment: Да, помогло. Спасибо!
Теперь вопрос в другом, если я закину это на хост, то таймер будет сбрасываться каждый раз?

Comment: @MADARA Разумеется. Это начинает работать только в момент загрузки страницы. Если надо именно отрываться от какого-то времени, сервер должен возвращать условную переменную. А можно и без сервера - сохранить на странице в HTML и из нее брать все время одно стартовое число.

Comment: Можно связаться с вам где-нибудь? В Telegram или WhatsApp? Не совсем понимаю, можно же создать еще MySQL базу и запихнуть это туда?

Comment: @MADARA Попробуй пока так: введи в консоль и скопируй текущее время `Date.now()`. И вместо постоянного обновления переменной `dateCreate`, установи это число на постоянку, например так `const dateCreate=1616600212607`